# Cocoa API to extract data from a Microsoft PowerPoint presentation

Tags: objective-c, c, macos, cocoa, powerpoint

Is there any API available in Cocoa(not COCOA-Touch) for a MAC OS based app that can extract data from a Microsoft PowerPoint presentation?
I need it for a Mac OS X-based application in which I need to read the contents of a presentation.

I need to extract the slides and template separately. Specifically, I need to:

1. Extract slides as images.
2. Extract the template as a separate PowerPoint template file.
3. Extract only the text in the slides.

I have done lot of googling, but found only that Applescript can interact with it. But it opens the presentation and then only it interacts with the presentation.

If there’s no API available, then what could be the best way to do this?

Comment: [This StackOverFlow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871494/reading-ppt-ms-powerpoint-file-in-cocoa-touch) provides one way. Substitute the WebKit WebView for a UIWebView and it should work more or less the same.

Comment: @JoshuaNozzi My requirement is different. The question has been edited. Adding to that, is there any framework available in C language that can communicate with PowerPoint??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Microsoft Office apps have an AppleScript interface that allows at least some access to the documents' inner structures. I have no experience with PowerPoint, but Excel works fine.

You can google for Microsoft AppleScript Reference.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already had found a reference document PPT2004AppleScriptRef. [http://download.microsoft.com/download/E/B/2/EB23A950-5EDC-4E68-B60F-25764AA7174 B/PPT2004AppleScriptRef.pdf](http://download.microsoft.com/download/E/B/2/EB23A950-5EDC-4E68-B60F-25764AA7174%20B/PPT2004AppleScriptRef.pdf) Also AppleScript Dictionary for Powerpoint is very useful. But still, I was not able to find something that can do these things in background. i.e. without opening the Powerpoint or in hidden mode. So, finally I am using Applescript.