# How to open ppt file from my app in mac

Tags: cocoa

I am new to Cocoa application development. Actually I want to open ppt file in my application and navigate between slides .can any one help me how to do this please .thanks in advance

Comment: One way for opening ppt file is write applescript and then call the same in cocoa please follow this link developer.apple.com/.../NSAppleScript_...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to take a look into a [Quick Look framework documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/UsingtheQuickLookFramework.html). You can only use Quick Look through the Preview panel ([QLPreviewPanel Class](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Quartz/Reference/QLPreviewPanel_Class/Reference/Reference.html)) API.

If this won't be sufficient for you you will need to code your own parser for PPT files. There is some info on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15971969/ios-library-to-convert-powerpoint-presentations-into-images/18129059#18129059), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871494/reading-ppt-ms-powerpoint-file-in-cocoa-touch) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5394443/parsing-powerpoint-into-one-image-per-slide). PPT's are basically XML documents so should not be such a problem.